# Multiple Parameter in REST-PUT with both @Path and @Body

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

REST-API PUT  with both @Path and @Body as input parameters

I am trying to create an API PUT method which should use both @Path and @Body as input parameters but cannot find the exact example(sample code) to achieve that.

Comment: Could you please post the existing code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample for your requirement.

```
@PUT("/api/{username}")
void putAPICall(@Path("username") String username, @Body RequestBody params);
```

Comment: Thanks @okcomputer_kid

Comment: @AbhilashGupta You are welcome. Do accept the answer if it solved the problem so that it will be useful for others as well.